# Converting RSS to JSON adds strange characters

Tags: ajax, json, rss

I'm trying to get an JSON version off the CNN Entertainment RSS feed, but it appears the Google AJAX script is adding strange characters. I looked into URL encoding which I know is important, but I don't think I'm using any characters that need encoding. Plus, the feed converter has no problems with the regular "edition." It's the "edition_entertainment" that seems to cause the problem.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_entertainment.rss

For example, the feed has strange slashes and added characters"

> still singing those \"Frozen\" tunes over a year later, you'll have a brand new set of
>   tunes in the not-too-distant future.\u003cimg src\u003d\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all standard encoding.
The original is:
"Frozen". Since json uses the " itself, the encoding enters a \ before each quote.

The \u003cimg src\u003d\" was

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I think JSON turns a quote into `\"` But what about `\u003cimg`?

Comment: The \u003cimg should be read as \u003c img which is < img (spaces added for clarity).
Once encoding is used, all special characters are encoded according to the standard.

Comment: Got it. So it's just encoding some HTML, no big deal. Thanks.